# WebStorm does not set environment variable

Tags: angular, environment-variables, webstorm

I've a problem with JetBrains WebStorm. I want to debug my Angular/JavaScript code so I have to start my application from "**Run/Debug configuration**".

I try to edit my configuration and set my npm configuration. I want to replicate the command `ng serve --env=local` to start my app. But I can not get this result.

How you can see in the pic:
[image]

[image]

I set the environment variable at `env=local`, but when I try to start I see the command launched is only `ng serve` not `ng serve --env=local` so my application not work and I can't debug my code from WebStorm.

[image]

How can I set the configuration to start my application with `ng serve --env=local`?

Answer (score 1):

To run your "ng" script with `serve --env=local`, you need modifying **Arguments** field accordingly - specify `-- serve --env=local` there:

[image]

See see docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Answer (score 0):

Put `--env=local` in Arguments input, not in the environment.

so in Run/Debug configuration window, arguments should be like this:

Arguments:  `serve --env=local`

Comment: Just `--env=local` won't work... You need prepending it with `--` separator to have args passed to the script. see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Comment: `build` and `serve` doesn't need prepending `--` when using ng .
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: this all is not about angular, it's about npm.